# Prawn Tables, Ruby adding tabs to string

Tags: ruby, string, pdf, prawn

I am building up a prawn document, there is a section with a table, and in the first column we have a list of bullet points like this.

[image: desired outcome]

Trying to replicate this exactly has become quite tough.

```
new_cell = make_cell(content: "•\t\tAdministration fee\n \t\t\t\t\t\t[Admin fee]", borders:[:bottom, :left, :right])
```

I have added the content to the cell but no matter what after the new line character I cannot get the `[admin fee]` bit to sit aligned like the image above.

[image: my current style]

It would seem as if my `\t` has no effect after the `\n` has been declared.

I have also tried the normal html escapes `&#160;` and `&nbsp;` and these will render out as if they are not escaped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about replacing the `\t` or `&#160;` and `&nbsp;` with `#{Prawn::Text::NBSP * number_required_for_spacing}`

Comment: That worked! I was wondering why Prawn wouldn't render those escaped characters. Seems as if Prawn has it's own helpers for this. Thanks bud!